# C# compiler complains about misusing local variable before when there are none

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Am I blind?  Where is the local variable?

1>d:\path\Start.cs(99,11,99,20): error CS0844: Cannot use local variable '_mainAssy' before it is declared. The declaration of the local variable hides the field

Also same error lines 100, 102, 105.

```
private AssyFile _mainAssy = null;
private AssyFile MainAssy()
{
  if (_mainAssy != null) // this is line 99.
     return _mainAssy;
  try
  {
    _mainAssy = new AssyFile(Application.ActiveDocument as AssemblyDocument);
  }
  catch
  {
    _mainAssy = documents.CreateAssy(); 
  }

  returrn _mainAssy;
}
```

EDIT: added missing try and catch statements.  (Before removed to try to resolve bug.
Current question is:  Why does mispelling 'return' cause this compiler message?

Comment: remove superfluous "{" and "}" to avoid compiler confusion

Comment: Also has typo `returrn` -> `return` that will be your next compile error

Comment: Yes maybe you forget an `else` before that second code block.

Comment: No, that is not a problem.  I found it:  returrn is spelled wrong.  WHY does that cause this error message?

Comment: because `returrn _mainAssy;` is considered a local variable declaration by the compiler. Of course, type `returrn` is not defined, but that's another issue.

Comment: Misspelling `return` turns the statement into a local variable declaration of a variable `_mainAssy` with the type `returrn` (yet to be defined). That's what causes the error.

Comment: To expand on the above, the new variable `_mainAssy` (declared at the end) takes over that identifier for the entire scope.  So earlier references that had been to a field are now pointing at that new variable (which hasn't been declared yet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
returrn _mainAssy;
```

Because you misspelled `return`, the compiler doesn't recognize the keyword. So it thinks `returrn` is a type, and `returrn _mainAssy` is the declaration for a variable `_mainAssy` of type `returrn`...